# I do not have access to the internet in service

Tags: android

I wrote a service where I send data to server. My problem here is that in version 4, when the app is closed, the service is available to the Internet And the data will be sent but When I tested on version 7 When the program closes The service does not have Internet access It seems like the operating system blocks internet access.
What should I do?
this my code

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements android.location.LocationListener {

      boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
      boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
      boolean canGetLocation = false;
      private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
      Location location; // location
      double latitude; // latitude
      double longitude; // longitude
      private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 1; // 10 meters
      private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = G.preferences.getInt(Const.PREF_DRIVER_STATUS_REQUEST_PERIOD, 10000); // 1 minute
      protected LocationManager locationManager;
      public GPSTracker() {
        getLocation();
      }
      @Override
      public int onStartCommand(Intent intent1, int flags, int startId) {
        getLocation();
        stopSelf();
        Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), com.rasef.app.driver.services.GPSTracker.class);
        intentAlarm.setAction(Const.SERVICE_STATUS_LOCATION_ACTION);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), Const.SERVICE_STATUS_LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE, intentAlarm, 0);
        G.alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + G.preferences.getInt(Const.PREF_STATUS_REQUEST_PERIOD, 10000), pendingIntent);
        return START_STICKY;
      }
      @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
      public Location getLocation() {
        try {
          locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
          isGPSEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
          isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

          if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
          } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
              locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
              Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
              if (locationManager != null) {
                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if (location != null) {
                  latitude = location.getLatitude();
                  longitude = location.getLongitude();
                  Log.d("Gps", latitude + "," + longitude);
                }
              }
            }
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
              if (location == null) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                  location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                  if (location != null) {
                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    Log.d("Network", latitude + "," + longitude);
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            if (location != null) {
              sendToServerLocation(location);
            } else {
            }
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return location;
      }
      private void sendToServerLocation(Location location) {
        // codes send to server with library retrofit
      }
      @Override
      public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        Log.i("Change", "Location:" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
      }

      @Override
      public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
      }

      @Override
      public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        return null;
      }
    }
```

Comment: I think you missed to put internet permission in Android manifest file. Can you show your manifest file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>

Comment: Works in version 4 even when the app is closed , 
It works in version 7, but When the app closed The service does not have Internet access In this version And data is not sent  and error connection time out

Comment: I found the problem , battery restriction mode , But I do not know how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Add the INTERNET permission to your manifest file.

You have to add this line:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: I added this permission. 
The problem is that it has access to the Internet as long as the app is open but When the program closes The service does not have Internet access

Comment: I found the problem , battery restriction mode , But I do not know how to fix it